# Non-intrusive serialize method for template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost-serialization

I am using boost serialization, mostly the intrusive version. For a template Matrix class I would like to have the [non-intrusive version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion) which works on Visual Studio with the following code:

```
namespace boost 
{
    namespace serialization 
    {

        template<class Archive, int R, int C, class ElementType>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, Matrix<R, C, ElementType> & m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & ...
        }

    } 
}
```

`int R`, `int C` are the row and columns, `ElementType` is `double` or `float`.

However, this does not work on GCC 4.3.2 with the error

```
error: 'class Matrix<1u, 3u, double>' has no member named 'serialize'
```

If I use a special form like

```
namespace boost 
{
    namespace serialization 
    {

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, Matrix<3,1,double> & m, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & ...
        }

    } 
}
```

it compiles on GCC, but of course only for a special set of template arguments.

What can I do to make it work on both compilers for all `R`, `C` and `ElementType`?

EDIT: These are the lines causing the error:

```
/[myfolder]/lib/BOOST/1_44_0/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In static member function 'static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive, T = Matrix<3u, 1u, double>]':
/[myfolder]/lib/BOOST/1_44_0/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:70: instantiated from 'void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive, T = Matrix<3u, 1u, double>]'
/[myfolder]/lib/BOOST/1_44_0/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:129: instantiated from 'void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive, T = Matrix<3u, 1u, double>]'
/[myfolder]/lib/BOOST/1_44_0/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:182: instantiated from 'void boost::archive::detail::iserializer<Archive, T>::load_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*, unsigned int) const [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive, T = Matrix<3u, 1u, double>]'
```

Comment: How do you invoke the serialize method?

Comment: boost calls it, please see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a signed/unsigned mismatch to me.  Your template function is declared with `int`s but the error indicates that the object which it's trying to match with the template has parameters `1u` and `3u`.  When you instantiate the object that you're trying to serialize, are you using unsigned values for the dimensions?  Try changing your serialize template function to take `unsigned`s or instantiating your Matrix with `int`s.